# Android dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid' has different version for the compile (16.0.0) and runtime (18.0.0) classpath

Tags: react-native

In my react native application i am integrating react-native-push-notification and getting this error.

app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "27.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried various solutions like changing from "implementaion" to "api" , in configuration.all adding check to fetch particular version of firebase-core, but nothing worked.

React Native version is 0.55.4

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
In my project's build.gradle buildscript->dependencies i replaced version of the google-services gradle plugin from "4.0.2" to "4.2.0" and it worked.

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

Answer (score -1):

The library `react-native-push-notification` has a dependency declared as '+' for the `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` in it's `build.gradle`. This will fetch the latest version of the library from maven repo.

This is clashing with your version declaration in your `android/app/build.gradle` file, which is `16.0.1`.

Add this to your project level `build.gradle`

```
ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "[your_desired_version]"
    firebaseVersion = "[your_desired_version]"
}
```